# Why is my sump pump still beeping after I replaced the battery?

Tags: sump-pump

My sump pump battery monitor was beeping.  I changed the battery because the message said that the battery was not working.  Not 24 hours later the battery was beeping again!  Do I need to do anything special since I just bought a new  marine battery from an auto parts store?  Any help would be greatly appreciated. The beeping is driving my crazy!!!

Answer (score 5):

These things have a battery AND a battery charger. You wanted to verify why the battery went dead. If the charger is not working (or maybe is not even plugged in?) then the new battery will die too.

Check that power is getting to it. Check that the charger is working. Check all connections.